# Disable the right click, ctrl +c , ctrl+v and selection functionalities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, web-applications

I am developing an Online Exam rails app. In the Examination interface, I want to prevent the copy(ctrl+c), paste(ctrl+v), right click and selection functionalities. How I would be able to prevent it using javascript? Please help me to have a better solution for this.

Thanks  :)-

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the client's browser, so you'll need to add the appropriate JScript to your page. Note that this only works if Javascript is enabled on their browser (it generally will be).